# GetText() doesn't work for me on EditText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i am using xaamarin i want to get edit text text

```
String us= ((EditText)findViewById(Resource.id.usr)).getText().toString();
String pw = ((EditText)findViewById(Resource.id.psw)).getText().toString();
String value1=us;
String value2=pw
```

when i use GetText() << it is erroring me
'Android.Widget.EditText' does not contain a definition for 'getText' and no extension method 'getText' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.EditText'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setter and getter like `setXYZ`, `getXyz` are mapped to the property `Xyz` in Xamarin, because this is more C#-like.

```
var us = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.usr).Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is problem in defining resource id (`Resource.id.usr`). It should be like this:

```
String us= ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.usr)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: I think this is not the cause of the problem.... wrongly mapped resources can compile fine

Comment: `R` is mappped to the class `Resource` in Xamarin :)

Comment: Syntax totally seems like native android.

Comment: it is C# using xamarin